# Strange behavior in Hibernate findById query

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a use case where Hibernate behaves in an unexpected way. The idea is that I have an entity with associations (albeit a lot of them, with both many to one and one to many links) and I want to do a findById query using the primary key of one of the entities. The problem is that the resulting entity does not have one of the associated manyToOne entities (again, this is the case for the biggest related entity). As more context, the base entity (the one used for the findBy query) also has a couple of "free text" fields, mapped as VARCHAR(1000) in mysql. What is weird in this case are the following:

1. This problem only occurs for a small sample of table entries. 90% of them just retrieve the entire tree without issues
2. Taking the query generated by hibernate and using it in mysql will result in a properly linked object (the id of the associated entity is retrieved in this join) even for this "problematic" id -> so the generated SQL is correct
3. The entry in question has some longer texts in the 2 VARCHAR(1000) columns (one is ~ 300 characters, the other is ~ 500 characters). If we trim one of the texts to a certain characters length, the query is successful for this id as well. Going further, if we decrease the characters of the other "free text" field, we can increase the characters for the first text field with the same amount of characters and the retrieval will still be successful. One character more and the query will not retrieve the related entity. Going even further, optimizing some of the relationships (making some "ToOne" associations as lazy) will allow more characters to be added to the "free text" fields without impacting the retrieval.

The immediate solution in this case is more likely to carefully re-design the associations and how much of the tree is retrieved with every query, but I am more curious about this behavior of the Hibernate framework. Does it have something like a limit to how many data/objects it can return or hydrate for a single fetch query? If it is so, what is the limit and can it be tweaked?

Frameworks used: Hibernate 5.3.9, Spring data 2.1.6, Java 8, Mysql 5.7 database

Thank you.

Comment: It might be usefull to log the sql statements sent to the database. Please see f.x. https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot on how to set up this logging. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hello Kaj. As you can see in the point "2" in the question, mainly "Taking the query generated by hibernate and using it in mysql will result in a properly linked object (the id of the associated entity is retrieved in this join) even for this "problematic" id" I am taking the sql statements and the bound parameters and use them in a mysql query myself.

Comment: I see. Sorry for commenting a bit to fast!

Comment: @AndreiZafiu did you solve this issue? Do you remember what the cause and solution was?